# Synapse Spark: Python logging to log file in Azure Data Lake Storage

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2, python-logging

I am working in Synapse Spark and building a logger function to handle error logging. I intend to push the logs to an existing log file (data.log) located in AzureDataLakeStorageAccount/Container/Folder/.

In addition to the root logger I have added a StreamHandler and trying to setup a FileHandler to manage the log file write-out.

The log file path I am specifying has path in this format: 'abfss:/container@storageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net/Data/logging/data.log'

When I run the below code, I get the following error:

*FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/var/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/trusted-service-user/appcache/application_<number/container_number/abfss:/container@storageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net/Data/logging/data.log'*

The default mount path is getting prefixed to the ADLS file path.

Here is the code:

'''

```
import logging

def init_logger(name: str, logging_level: int = logging.DEBUG) -> logging.Logger:    
    _log_format = "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(name)s: %(message)s"
    _date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p %z"
    _formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt=_log_format, datefmt=_date_format)

    _root_logger = logging.getLogger()
    _logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    _logger.setLevel(logging_level)

    #Root and Stream Handler 
    if _root_logger.handlers:
        for handler in _root_logger.handlers:
            handler.setFormatter(_formatter)

        _logger.setLevel(logging_level)
    else:
        _handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
        _handler.setLevel(logging_level)
        _handler.setFormatter(_formatter)
        _logger.addHandler(_handler)

    __handler = logging.FileHandler(LogFilepath, 'a')
    __handler.setLevel(logging_level)
    __handler.setFormatter(_formatter)
    _logger.addHandler(__handler)

    return _logger
```

'''

To address the mount path prefix I added a series of '../' to move level up but even with this I end up with a solitary '/' prefixed to my ADLS path.

I have not found any online assistance or article where this has been implemented in an Azure Data Lake setup. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error, it seems to be the path of the file might be the issue here. Instead of giving the `abfss` path, you can try by giving the path like `/synfs/{jobid}/<mount point>/filepath`.

Use the below code for that.

```
jobid=mssparkutils.env.getJobId()
LogFilepath='/synfs/'+jobid+'/<mount_point>/filename.log'
print(LogFilepath)
```

[image]

The above path might work for you. If not, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75280414/synapse-spark-exception-handling-cant-write-to-log-file/75308667#75308667) method `with open()` as an alternative for logging to an ADLS file.